# Prevent add to cart if subtotal is zero in Woocommerce: not able to get the subtotal before adding to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have setup a product with woo variation swatches, variations has been setup as checkbox group and each variation has different price, so the customer can select the products they want and the price of each variation they select will be added to the total. it's working and I am able to add to the cart with the calculated price. But if no variation is selected, the price remains 0 and gets added to the cart with 0 as subtotal, I want to prevent the product from being added to the cart if price is zero.

I tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 3 );
function my_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity  ) {
   $amount =  WC()->cart->subtotal;
   if( $amount == 0 ) {
    wc_add_notice( "Pls select a product", "error" );
     $passed = false;
   }
  return $passed;
}
```

I have tried the following

```
global $woocommerce; 

        $amount =  WC()->cart->get_total('raw') ;
        $amount1 =  WC()->cart->subtotal;
        $amount2 = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
        $amount3 = $woocommerce->cart->total;
        $amount4 = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
        $amount5 = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
        $amount6 = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
        $amount7 = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
        $amount8 = WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal();
```

but the total amount is zero always, not able to get the subtotal before adding to the cart. the total is zero even when I have variations selected and total (>0) has been calculated on the product page

Comment: the price is zero when I am trying to get the total in my functions.php, even when I have some variations selected on the product page and it displays the total with prices for variations in the cart and checkout page.

Comment: it  happens on simple products without any variations, i have disabled ajax for add to cart in template and in woocommerce for archive pages. I am not able to get the subtotal in functions.php regardless of what I try. I will check the client side too.

Comment: I have checked it after deactivating the plugin, I can't get the subtotal in functions.php of my theme on any product when they are added to the cart, it displays the total perfectly in the cart and checkout pages, but not able to do cart validation in functions.php as I am not  able to get the subtotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cart is empty and you add a product to the cart (for the first time) the value of `WC()->cart->subtotal` used inside the hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` will always return zero. Because this check happens before the product is added to the cart and therefore the subtotal is not updated yet.

**You should use a Javascript (or jQuery) script to disable the "Add to cart" button** if no checkbox has been checked *(as is already the case with the select options if none are selected)*.

This way you can be sure that the price will always be greater than zero when the user clicks on "Add to cart".

Comment: Yes, this is my first woocommerce site and I though I can fetch the subtotal before it was added to the cart, but that's not possible. Thank you for confirming it., I simply dumped the $_POST and completed the cart validation based on the check boxes (variations) selected.